# can not render api data with map

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

[image]I was trying to fetch api and i have got data (you can see in the console {respons} ).
but when ever i am trying to rendering data using map app get crash. [[image: you can see the fetch respons in the console1]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsDpS.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsDpS.png)

[image: this is my api]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/user')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setItems(data));
```

You need to convert the response to JSON array in order to map it

Answer (score 0):

Before you loop through your response you must check if item has value,

The way code renders on frontend is, it tries to execute your jsx and when useEffect gets response it re renders the screen.

If you closely see your console log, in first render it was empty, then it has logged value.

The solution to this is to add AND condition before looping like below

{items.length > 0 && items.map(item....

Answer (score 0):

You can see from your `console.log` that `response` is not an array, but a full HTTP response object. If you look at `response.data`, you'll see that it's a buffer at that moment in time, because the response will arrive as a stream. You need to collect the response in full and parse it to JSON before you can use it.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) to see how you can do this.

Comment: Thank you. I have figured it out.